# How to pass data into sub view that the sub view can not change

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am very new to Swift and SwiftUI and trying to work out how to achieve the following.

1. `ContentView` creates two `User` objects (player and cpu)
2. `ContentView` passes those objects to a sub view `ScoreView`
3. `ScoreView` should print properties from `User` (eg score and name)
4. `ScoreView` needs to be updated when `User.score` changes

This is what I have so far, and it works. However I am concerned that since there is a `@Binding` attached to the variable in `ScoreView` it could change the values. I would prefer this view to have these values as read only.

```
class User: ObservableObject {
    var name: String
    @Published var score: Int
    
    init(name: String, score: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.score = score
    }
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var player = User(name: "Player", score: 0)
    @StateObject var cpu = User(name: "CPU", score: 0)
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("background-plain").resizable().ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Image("logo")
                Spacer()
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    ScoreView(name: $player.name, score: $player.score)
                    Spacer()
                    ScoreView(name: $cpu.name, score: $cpu.score)
                    Spacer()
                }
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct ScoreView: View {
    
    @Binding var name: String
    @Binding var score: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(name)
                .font(.headline)
                .padding(.bottom, 10)
            Text(String(score))
                .font(.largeTitle)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
@Binding var
```

With

```
let
```

Then remove the `$` from the parent, where the two connect.

You should also change your `User` to a value type.

```
struct User {
    var name: String
    var score: Int
    
    init(name: String, score: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.score = score
    }
}
```

Comment: If I do this, then the `ScoreView` never updates. If I change the score, it keeps the old value printed to the screen.

Comment: @Charklewis I missed that make your user a struct you can’t chain observable objects and expect SwiftUI to know when there are changes

Comment: Actually it does work! I had a bug in my code that wasn't correctly updated the scores. Making the change you suggested does allow the view to get updated.

Comment: Can do! I will have to learn more about structs and classes.